# Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 3.0 or higher

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello flutter developer i am facing issue in flutter while compile the code issue that if i run and compile my code in flutter framwork my app runs fine but issue that when i open android module and run app it will not work not building apk Here is error below please check

Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip.dart:66:10: Error: The 'class-modifiers' language feature is disabled for this library.

Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 3.0 or higher.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAu0Q.jpg)

```
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 3.0 or higher.
abstract interface class ChipAttributes {
         ^^^^^^^^^
/Applications/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/chip.dart:221:10: Error: The 'class-modifiers' language feature is disabled for this library.
Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 3.0 or higher.
abstract interface class DeletableChipAttributes {
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade flutter to latest stable version.

Run `flutter channel beta` and `flutter upgrade`.

You also will need to change dart sdk version in pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.0-0 <4.0.0'
```

Comment: i am using. environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0' this version

Comment: Switching channel may help